# In python how can I have 2 loops where the second one returns to the first one once a given condition is met?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I am new to programming, and for fun i thought i would create a login/register system that works through the terminal with inputs. My problem is I have 2 while loops, and they both check to see if a variable called loggedin is equal to true or false. When you login during the first loop, It sets loggedin equal to True so that the second loop will start, but if you logout during the second loop, I want it to return you to the first loop where it asks you to login or register. I tried to accomplish this by having it so when you input logout it sets the logginin variable equal to false, hence bringing you back to the first loop, but instead it just quits the program! People have told me to use functions, but I am not sure how to implement this into my program. Thank you for any help you can offer me.

```
import time

loggedin = False
users = {}
mail = {}

print("Welcome to the network\nIf you have an account, type login\nIf you have no account, type register.\n")

while loggedin == False:
    option = input("register/login > ")

    if option.lower() != "login" and option.lower() != "register":
        print("That is not an option")

    elif option == "register":
        print("REGISTER\nType in your new username")
        while True:
            newusername = input("> ")
            if len(newusername) > 0 and newusername.isalpha():
                break
            else:
                print("This is not a valid username")
        while True:
            print("Type in your new password")
            newpassword = input("> ")
            if len(newpassword) > 0 and newpassword.isalpha():
                print("Account has been created")
                users[str(newusername)] = str(newpassword)
                mail[newusername] = []
                break
            else:
                print("This is not a valid password")

    else:
        print("Type your username")
        while True:
            username = input("> ")
            if str(username) in users:
                break
            else:
                print("Username not found")

        print("Type your password")
        while True:
            password = input("> ")
            if str(password) == users[username]:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Password correct")
                print("Logging in")
                loggedin = True
                break
            else:
                print("Password incorrect")

print("Welcome to your account " + username)
print("OPTIONS: view mail | send mail | logout")
while loggedin == True:
    option = input("> ")
    if option.lower() != "view mail" and option.lower() != "send mail" and option.lower() != "logout":
        print("Invalid option")
    elif option == "send mail":
        while True:
            print("Type the username of the person you would like to send mail to")
            recipient = input("> ")
            if str(recipient) not in mail:
                print("There is no one with that username!")
                break
            else:
                print("Enter subject")
                subject = input("> ")
                print("Enter context")
                context = input("> ")
                sender = username
                mail[recipient] = ["Sent from: " + str(sender),"Subject: " + str(subject),"Context" + str(context)]
                time.pause(1)
                print("Mail has been sent!")
                break
    elif option == "view mail":
        print("Current mail")
        print(mail)
    else:
        print("Logging out")
        loggedin = False
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want a `loop to return somewhere else`, it is usually an indicator, that you'd better use a function instead ;)

Ok, here is an updated code:

```
import time

def readUsername():
    while True:
        newusername = input("> ")
        if len(newusername) > 0 and newusername.isalpha():
            return newusername
        else:
            print("This is not a valid username")
            continue

def registerUser(username):
    while True:
        print("Type in your new password")
        newpassword = input("> ")
        if len(newpassword) > 0 and newpassword.isalpha():
            print("Account has been created")
            users[str(username)] = str(newpassword)
            mail[username] = []
            break
        else:
            print("This is not a valid password")

loggedin = False
users = {}
mail = {}

print("Welcome to the network\nIf you have an account, type login\nIf you have no account, type register.\n")

while loggedin == False:
    option = input("register/login > ")

    if option.lower() != "login" and option.lower() != "register":
        print("That is not an option")

    elif option == "register":
        print("REGISTER\nType in your new username")
        newusername = readUsername()
        registerUser(newusername)

    else:
    ....
```

Comment: That didn't work at all, It just exited the program.

Comment: Take a look at how you can use functions. I rewrote first part of your code, introducing two functions: `readUsername()` and `registerUser()`. You can do just the same thing with the remaining code (leaving it to you as an exercise ;) )

Comment: The `continue` in the first function is not necessary, because you have `while True` loop, which will not stop until you enter a valid `newusername`

Answer (score 0):

"Return to the first" is just another loop:

```
while True:
    while not loggedIn:
        # do login/register
    while loggedIn:
        # do other stuff
```